# Почему не фильтрует когда оба не пусто?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
if (!empty($country_id) && !empty($service_id)) { // если переменные с ID таксономий не пусты, то добавляем tax_query с отношением "И"
    $args['relation'] = 'AND';
}
if (!empty($service_id)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_obj,
        'terms'    => $service_id
    );
}
if (!empty($country_id)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_syst,
        'terms'    => $country_id
    );
}
```

Comment: потому что у одной и той же записи таблицы одно и то же поле не может быть равно двум разным значениям одновременно. если бы это было в запросе sql то понадобилось бы условие or, потом group by и подсчет совпадений в having (если я конечно правильно предположил структуру таблицы на основе php кода)

Comment: 'OR', а не 'AND'